# Executing an HTA Application via PSEXEC with command line arguments

Tags: powershell, cmd, hta, psexec

I have an `.hta` application that accepts two command line arguments. Executing the application on the remote machine via command line works just like the following

(command line - cmd)Example:

```
C:\Users\<user>\Desktop>MSI-BUILDER.hta "MSI_APP" "D:\APP\15.9.98"
```

But when using my desktop trying to execute the same command on the remote machine via PSEXEC I see the application running in task manager but nothing happens.

The first steps were assigning the command line arguments to variables in PowerShell:

```
$arg1 = "MSI_APP"
$arg2 = "D:\APP\15.9.98"
```

and executing this command in PowerShell fails (no errors, just hangs):

```
.\psexec -s -i \\Srv2012 cmd /c "start /i "MSI-BUILDER" "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\MSI-BUILDER.hta" $arg1 $arg2"
```

The application launches just in task manager and I'm assuming in the background but I don't see any changes, so it might just be hanging...

Im not 100% sure if my syntax in this matter is correct for launching an HTA via powershell with command-line arguments.

Also is there a way or switch that I can actually *see* the application launch and do its thing after remotely executing the code, for testing purposes?

Comment: "is there a way or switch that I can actually see the application launch and do its thing after remotely executing the code" - No. A remotely executed application will not be visible to the interactive user's GUI on a remote machine. This is by design for security reasons.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: `psexec` _can_ remotely launch applications visibly in a locally logged-on user's desktop session, namely via the `-i` option - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

Comment: Open up a Command Prompt window and enter both `start /?` and `cmd /?` to find out how those particular commands work. You'll note that the `start` command will require a title, an empty one will do, `start "" ...`, you'll also see a section under `cmd /?` which explains about how it handles doublequotes with `/C`. However, you shouldn't need to run your HTML application via `cmd.exe` or use its internal `start` command at all.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the notice. It can do this because it installs a service on the remote machine and then invokes the executable in the console (or a specified) session.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay so finally after hours of trying different things this is the command that worked for me

Edited Command:

```
.\PSEXEC -accepteula -s -i 2 \\SERVER cmd /c "D:\path\toapp\app.hta" $arg1 $arg2 -u username -p password
```

Comment: I think you meant `-i` instead of `-h` (which is essentially implied by `-s`); please note the security implications of running an _interactive_ program with `-s`; by using `cmd /c`, a console window will briefly appear on the target machine first.

Comment: Thanks for updating. `-i`  _without a session-ID argument_ is smart and automatically picks the session that is currently the interactive one on the target machine (the session named `console`). Using session _IDs_ such as `2` may work situationally, but the IDs change depending on who logged on first.

Comment: Also, using _both_ `-s` and `-u` + `-p` is contradictory; while `psexec` quietly accepts this combination, it is `-s` that takes effect, regardless of argument order.

Comment: @mklement0 Unfortunately that was my original direction using ```mshta.exe``` but the application would hang and never return a code from PowerShell which i kinda need to continue processing my functions with cmd I get a ```cmd exited on Srv2012 with error code 0.``` which I can return to my php script. Which is more than sufficient

Comment: -d just launches the app and returns successfully regardless of the end result, as for cmd /c it launches a windows waits for the application to close then closes itself returning a true success response.

Comment: So the HTA literally accepts two arguments and runs about 25-30 vbs scripts with those arguments once it iterates though the 25-30 scripts its set to ```window.close``` when that happens the cmd window closes because the process terminates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Note that HTA applications don't support setting exit codes explicitly, unless you employ [an elaborate workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823905/45375). Without it, the exit code would always be `0` - unless the `mshta.exe` process _crashes_. To summarize: we're back to square one: make `psexec` invoke `mshta.exe` _directly_ - without `-d` - and it will wait for the exit code, as desired - no need for `cmd /c`. I've updated my answer to contrast the two scenarios (synchronous vs. asynchronous).

Answer (score 2):

The **invocation of your `*.hta` file can be simplified**, by **passing its path and arguments directly to `mshta.exe`** (this also prevents a console window from appearing briefly if you launch via `cmd/ c`):

```bash
# From PowerShell (-accepteula omitted for brevity)
# IMPORTANT: You must use the *.hta file's FULL PATH.
.\psexec \\SERVER -i -s mshta.exe "D:\path\toapp\app.hta" $arg1 $arg2
```

**By default, [`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) runs *synchronously***, i.e. it doesn't return until the remote process *exits*, which is necessary if you want to know the process' *exit code*.<sup>[1]</sup>

In your case, the process doesn't exit *until the HTA application window closes*, so I assume that yours *automatically closes* when invoked with command-line arguments - if it doesn't, `psexec` wouldn't return until the interactive user closes the window when invoked with `-i`, or not at all without `-i`.

**In cases where you need *asynchronous* execution**, use the **`-d`** option; this makes `psexec` return after successfully *launching* the target process, without waiting for it to exit. Since you then by definition cannot know the true *exit* code of the launched process, all that `psexec` will tell you is whether the process could be *created*.

**Caveat**: Running *interactively* (`-i`) with `-s`, i.e. as the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account, is a **security risk** - see next section.

However, with proper quoting your original attempt could be made to work too - see the bottom section.

---

As for:

> Also is there a way or switch that I can actually *see* the application launch?

It is **`psexec`'s `-i` option** that **makes the specified command run *visibly, interactively* on the remote target machine**, *in the session of whatever user happens to be logged on there interactively at the time*.<sup>[2]</sup>

In terms of **user identity**, `psexec` generally allows you to launch commands as:

- either: **the `SYSTEM` account (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`)** with option **`-s`**, which is *not* recommended with `-i`, however:

  - `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is a *highly privileged* account that represents the local computer, so its use in an application *that the user can control interactively* is a a **security risk**.
- or: **a *given, fixed user*, with option `-u`** (and `-p`; see example below)

Note that **what you *cannot* do with `-i` is to *automatically* run *with the identity of* whatever user happens to be logged on to the interactive session on the target computer**, as that would be highly problematic from a security perspective. However, *explicitly* using `-u` with the same credentials as the currently interactive user (if known) works.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) for more information.

**With `-i`**, it's better to **use an account that has only the *minimum set of privileges required* for the application to function**; instead of `-s`, you would then use the `-u` (username) and `-p` (password) parameters; e.g.:

```bash
# From PowerShell
.\psexec \\SERVER -i -u user1 -p passwd1 mshta.exe "D:\path\toapp\app.hta" $arg1 $arg2
```

---

As for **what you tried** (in your question):

Your original command probably would have worked, if you had fixed your quoting problems:

```bash
.\psexec \\Srv2012 -s -i cmd /c start /i `"MSI-BUILDER`" "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\MSI-BUILDER.hta" $arg1 $arg2
```

To avoid problems with *nested* quoting, the outer quoting around the command passed to `cmd /c` has been omitted.

Note how the `"` chars. that enclose `MSI-BUILDER` must - unfortunately - be escaped as `` `" `` so as to *ensure* that PowerShell passes them through to `psexec` and, ultimately, `cmd /c`:

- PowerShell uses a *double-quoting on demand* policy behind the scenes, so that even arguments that you *originally specified* with quotes end up *not* double-quoted, *if the argument value doesn't contain spaces*<sup>[3]</sup> - therefore, your `"MSI-BUILDER"` argument ends up getting passed as just `MSI-BUILDER` - without double-quoting - to `psexec`.
- Unfortunately, the `cmd`-internal `start` command has an awkward syntax: it *always* requires the argument that is the *window title* to be enclosed in `"..."` on the command line, even if the title is a single word (such as `MSI-BUILDER` in your case).
- Therefore, in this particular edge case, the `"` around the window-title argument for `start` must be escaped as `` `" `` to ensure that they are retained.

As shown above, however, there's a simpler way to invoke your `*.hta` (not requiring an intermediate `cmd.exe` process).

As an aside: the `start`  command is superfluous, and setting a *title* for the transient window that launches the `*.hta` GUI is pointless, as the window will just flash for an instant.

---

<sup>[1] Note that HTA applications don't support setting exit codes explicitly, unless you employ [an elaborate workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823905/45375). Without it, the exit code would always be `0` - unless the `mshta.exe` process *crashes*.</sup>

<sup>[2] That `psexec` is capable of doing so may be surprising; it is made possibly by the following clever technique: `psexec` connects to the target machine's `$ADMIN` share (typically, `C:\Windows`), *temporarily* extracts a service executable that is embedded in its own executable image (`PSEXESVC.exe`) to that location, and starts that executable as *local service* (`PSEXESVC`) on the target machine. It is this service that launches the command passed to `psexec` on invocation, optionally in the current user's session (visible window station) (`-i`). The calling `psexec` instance on the origin machine communicates with the service via a named pipe (`psexecsvc`), which is what enables the calling machine to receive the remote process' *console output* assuming that `-i` was *not* specified; on completion of the command (or, with the `-d` (don't wait) option, on successfully *launching* the command), the service is stopped and the service executable is *deleted* - see [this article](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/psexec) for more information.</sup>

<sup>[3] There are other, complex criteria relating to `"` chars. *embedded* in the value.</sup>