# Run RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry remotely for Printer Settings Update

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have admin for same account on 2 Windows 2016 servers. Server1 has this folder\file: 'E:\Temp\ZEBRA_1.dat'

If I open PowerShell (v4 or v5) (as admin) on Server1 and run this line of code everything works as expected (printer settings are updated via .dat file):

```
start-process -Verb runas -filepath "C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE"  -argumentlist "PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n `"ZEBRA_1`" /a `"E:\Temp\ZEBRA_1.dat`" 2 7 c d g u"
```

If I then open PowerShell (as admin) on Server2 and enter the same code wrapped in an Invoke-Command it looks like the code runs (no errors), but when I check on Server1 - no changes were made:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server1' -ScriptBlock {
   start-process -Verb runas -filepath "C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE"  -argumentlist "PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n `"ZEBRA_1`" /a `"E:\Temp\ZEBRA_1.dat`" 2 7 c d g u"
}
```

I have tried wrapping the `Start-process` piece in a with `New-PSSession` to Server1 which also did not work. Using in the  `-Credential` arg my admin credentials also does not work on the with Invoke-Command.

If I mess with the "s then I get errors or no response, if I put the file on Server2 and use UNC path it still does not work from Server2 (but it still works from Server1).

I assume this is a RunAs Admin related issue since if the command is not run as admin on Server1 it will look as though it completes by also does not do anything.

How do I get that printer updated with that .DAT file remotely?

### UPDATE:

Note that when running this command locally it works seemingly instantly and there are never any popups or warnings generated.

I tried:

1. moving files to C and running - same behavior (scriptblock part runs locally but not remotely)
2. removed `-verb runas` - same behavior
3. removed `start-process` - same behavior
   `Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Server1' -ScriptBlock { C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "ZEBRA_1" /a "C:\Temp\ZEBRA_1.dat" 2 7 c d g u }`
4. added `-asJob` - same behavior except job info was written to host
5. adding `-wait` - printer was not updated BUT 2 processes were created and did not go away until I killed them (rundll32.exe and wsmprovhost.exe)
6. replaced `invoke-command` with a session - same behavior as #5 except killing the session killed the stalled processes for me

```
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'Server1'
     Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {
        C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "ZEBRA_1" /a "C:\Temp\ZEBRA_1.dat" 2 7 c d g u
     }
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
Remove-PSSession -Id $sess.Id
```

All this said, the hung rundll32.exe & wsmprovhost.exe processes seem the most suspicious - and they are of course invisible - but is there any way to get useful info back from them via the session?

### UPDATE 2

After much fiddling based on @mklement0's answer the following code works - not really a fan of using psexec.exe because of additional file overhead, but I will take what I can get at this point. Interestingly, psexec's -i switch was not needed (big help with debugging though).

```
$server = 'Server1'; $localDatFolder = 'e:\Temp\'; $printer = 'ZEBRA_1'

$credential = Get-Credential -Message 'U & P for printersettings'
$user = "MyDomain\$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().UserName)" 
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password

$ARGS = @('PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry', '/Sr', $('/n"'+$printer+'"'), $('/a"'+$localDatFolder+$printer+'.dat"'), '2', '7', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'u')
e:\temp\pstools\psexec.exe \\$server -u $user -p $password C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE $ARGS
```

Finally
If I did not care about adjusting my personal preferences this code works. Seems like it should work without psexec since it's just using system and not interreacting but I was never able to make it happen

```
#THIS WORKS IF NOT ADJUSTING PERSONAL SETTINGS TOO:  
$server = 'Server1'; $localDatFolder = 'e:\Temp\'; $printer = 'ZEBRA_1'    
$ARGS = @('PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry', '/Sr', $('/n"'+$printer+'"'), $('/a"'+$localDatFolder+$printer+'.dat"'), '2', '7', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'u')    
e:\temp\pstools\psexec.exe \\$server -s C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE $ARGS
```

Comment: My guess is E is a mapped drive? This definitely sounds like a [double-hop issue](https://www.ipswitch.com/blog/the-infamous-double-hop-problem-in-powershell)

Comment: thanks for trying to help with this @DougMaurer - see results of your suggestions above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using `-Verb RunAs` in a [*remote*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call is pointless, but usually benign:

  - By default, only administrators are permitted to make remoting calls, and their remote sessions *invariably* run *with elevation* (with administrative privileges), so that `-Verb RunAs` is neither necessary nor has any effect.
  - In the unusual event that you've explicitly allowed *non*-administrators to run remote commands, *on-demand elevation* cannot work, because no UAC dialog can be presented in the remote session, which runs *invisibly*.
- Therefore, you may not even need to use `Start-Process` remotely.

  - That is, *direct* invocation should do (but note the additional, network-related problem below): `C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE ...`
  - If you do use `Start-Process`, you *must* use its `-Wait` switch to ensure that the command completes before the `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...` call returns, as the the launched process may otherwise get *terminated* before it has a chance to finish.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Additionally, as [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) notes, you're probably running into the infamous *double-hop problem*, which prevents your remotely running commands from accessing *network resources*.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692809/45375) for one way to work around the problem, by passing credentials explicitly to the remote session, which can use them to establish a (temporary) drive mapping to the network resource.
  - As a potential alternative, Doug points to the solution presented in [this blog post](https://www.ipswitch.com/blog/the-infamous-double-hop-problem-in-powershell), which involves creating a session configuration with a fixed domain-user identity on the target machine; however, this approach:

    - may not work with *non*-domain user identities
    - even with domain identities may be prevented by network security policies
    - is a potential security risk, because whatever user connects via this session configuration then uses the preconfigured user identity.
- If you've heeded all the advice above and the `C:\Windows\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE` call still doesn't work as expected:

  - A *conceivable* reason is if the specific DLL call being made requires a *window station*, i.e. the same type of environment you get *interactively*, and therefore fails to run in the invisible, desktop-less session that PowerShell remoting commands run in.
  - A *possible* solution is therefore to use [`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) instead of PowerShell remoting, with its `-i` and `-h` options; note, however, that `-i` *requires a (any) user to be logged on interactively on the target machine*; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57982729/45375) for an example.

---

<sup>[1] Using [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-ComputerName` parameter creates an *ad-hoc session* that is closed when the call returns. By contrast, an *explicitly created* session, via [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession) that is passed to `Invoke-Command` via `-Session` is longer-lived (at least 2 hours by default, unless closed earlier with an explicit [`Remove-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-pssession) call). However, it is still better to run all commands *synchronously* in the *remote* session. If the *caller* doesn't want to wait for the results synchronously, it can use the `Invoke-Command`'s `-AsJob` parameter to receive a [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs) object that can be queried for completion and results later, on demand.</sup>

Comment: thanks for trying to help with this @mklement0 - see results of your suggestions above

Comment: @casewolf: Note that you have to make sure that file `C:\Temp\ZEBRA_1.dat` is available _on the remote machine_, given that that it is interpreted as a _local_ path there. Have you ensured that?

Comment: yes it is there, in fact it is there on both machines just in case! haha

Comment: @casewolf, please see my update (new bullet point at the bottom); in short: `psexec -i` _may_ help.

Comment: the psexec did do the trick, did not need -i switch interestingly. thanks for your help

Comment: @casewolf: Not needing `-i` is curious, but I'm glad it worked.